# iPhone - NavigationBar Custom Background

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add background image on iphone Navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar)

I am looking for a way to have a custom navigation bar and need to have a custom navigation bar background to achieve this. I was looking around for how to do this, but could not find a solution. If anyone has the solution, help is much appreciated.

Comment: There more solutions alternative solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add a subview (a UIImageView) to the navaigationBar, which is just a UIView subclass.

```
UINavigationBar nb = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
[nb addSubview: foo];
[nb release];
```

Here's a forum post that describes how to wrap this up into a category: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1649012&tstart=0

Answer (score 14):

Since iOS5, you can easily set a custom background, with the method *setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:*
But you must check if the user's phone has the right OS.

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture.png"]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

This is a nicer solution, cause it's in the doc.

Comment: Until a user that isn't running iOS5 runs your app

Comment: Yes, but there is a check for that. You can make something else in the else clause.

Answer (score 10):

(supplemental to Andrew Johnson's response)

The linked Apple.com post includes 3 or 4 different solutions, most of which only "half" work. I think the most elegant/effective of them is this one:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

HOWEVER ... it's not good-practice ObjC to od that as a category (should be an override), and it has some problems of its own.

So, a more general and powerful solution is here:

http://samsoff.es/posts/customize-uikit-with-method-swizzling

Comment: Thanks for linking to me Adam :) You're right that overriding methods with categories is a very bad practice.

Comment: Someone downvoted this without explanation? Not sure why. Although I would add: this whole question (and most of the answers) are iOS 2/3/4 only - iOS 5 has a whole new system of doing this. The answer still works for the people that are doing iOS4.

Answer (score 3):

Copy this into viewDidLoad. It will check for iOS 5 and use the preferred method, otherwise it will add a subview to the navBar for iOS versions < 5.0. This will work provided that your custom background image has no transparencies.

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f",version);
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundImage.png"];
if (version >= 5.0) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease] atIndex:1];
}
```