# Setting background image of navigation bar for two different OSs

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I am using following code to set the background image for the navigation bar for iPhone OS 5:
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab bar.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

If I create the build for iPhone running OS Version 5...will it pose any problem if someone download the app and try to run on the device running OS version lesser 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` is not available on iOS 4 or lower.
Thus calling this method will crash your app.

Just check if the object respons to selector:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab bar.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Beware that the over ridding the `drawRect:` method used in iOS 4 and lower does not work in iOS 5. Thus you have to implement both ways to get your app working on iOS 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes. You better check for the current iOS version before calling the method. --- Alternatively declare your App as compatible for iOS 5+ only. That prevents it from being installed on older OS. However, a quick check of the iOS version is not too difficult.

Comment: Beter yet just check if the method is available with the `respondsToSelector` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```
 - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

> ```
> Available in **iOS 5.0 and later.**
> ```

So you should check for the current iOS version and on IOS 5 use:

```
 setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics.
```

and if you want to set the background in 4.0 here is the answer describing how to do it wither by adding a subview or using a category:

[iPhone - NavigationBar Custom Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259929/iphone-navigationbar-custom-background)

Answer (score 0):

// Add the QuartzCore frameowrk in .h file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

// If you want set different image for every view.Write this code in `viewWillAppear` method 
// `NavigationBar` background image.

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    //For iOS >= 5
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else {
    //For iOS < 5
    NSString *barBgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"topbar" ofType:@"png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setContents:(id)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: barBgPath].CGImage];
}
```