# Insert a image in UINavigationBar instead of text

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

i have this piece of code which permits me to insert a title on the UIbar (if i'm not wrong) of the app.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ApplicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(goToAlbum) name:@"GetAlbumNotif" object:nil];
self.title = @"Events List";
```

Can you please give me an orientation to this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add an image to the center of the navigationBar?
Do you want to add a UIBarButton with an image inside?
Please give some more information!

Comment: I need to add an image to the center of the navigation bar please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Comment: Now i may sound dumb but i have no other choice, it is supposed to work just by copy-pasting this code? am i suppose to declare anything else elsewhere?

Comment: just replace `self.title = @"Events List";` with my code and change it to the right image name. And you should start reading some of the Apple documentations before you ask to many questions here!

Comment: Thank you, you're right i should start reading, i have indeed, but hey i tried this code, and it won't display the image there..

Comment: there is something like a breakpoint, there is a button, a reload button on the bar..

Answer (score 0):

A UIBarButton is inside a NavigationBar. The easiest way is to add a UIBarButton to the NavigationBar in the Interface Builder.
After that, you can alter the background with:

```
[barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can change the appearance of a navigation bar if your deployment target is iOS 5.0 or higher with :

```
[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
```

Or do the old fashion way with subclassing UINavigationBar and override drawInRect. How to do that can be found here:
[How to add background image on iphone Navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar)