# How to add an image in the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I want to add an image in the navigation bar. It should be throughout my app. It should be added to all navigation controllers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this link also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ,

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add image with bellow code..

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"yourImageName.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
          UITextAttributeTextColor,
          [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
          UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],
          UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0],
          UITextAttributeFont,
          nil]];
    }
```

**put this in your Appdelegate.m**

Answer (score 2):

u use this code:

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

i am an ideal , because i have got issue like this ,so you can try my way,ok!!

the first,you create an navigationcontroller and then show it on window

`UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:YourView];`

next step : you create an object Uiimageview with image property  with your image which you want to add navigationbar and frame ptoperty is posittion which you want

`UIImageView *imgView=[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImagename"];
   imgView.Frame=CGrectmake();`

last step: you add object imgView in navigationbar as subview

```
[nav.navigationBar addSubview:imgView];
```

Done!!!!!!!!!!